# fast forward from current time to 7am and have not found a way to do so

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, raspberry-pi3

```
from datetime import datetime
print("The time is",datetime.now(),"and you should sleep now")
```

An example of the current time is 2017-12-16 21:24:02.620893 and I want the time to be fast forwarded to 7am the next day. how would I do that?

Comment: well datetime reads from the system clock so you would have to change that

Comment: Do you want to _display_ the date and time of 7am tomorrow, or do you want the system clock to actually be _set_ to that time?

Comment: go from any time and the program display 7am the next morning, as if the night has been skipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `timedelta()` to advance the day to tomorrow, then use `replace()` to set the hour, minutes, and seconds.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

tomorrow_now = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow_7am = tomorrow_now.replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

You could skip using `timedelta()` and just use `replace()` for everything, but you would need special handling for the last day of the month.

Comment: I just noticed that my answer was identical to this one but yours was uploaded a few minutes earlier. I'm deleted my answer but updated yours with a microsecond parameter for the replace() method, which you seem to have forgotten.

Comment: This doesn't work if `datetime.now()` is after midnight.